# How should I overlay a grid on a LeafletJs Map?

Tags: leaflet

I have a LeafletJs Map with a Lat / Lon graticule.  However what I would like at this point is to overlay a grid on the map with a fixed number of rows & columns (say, 19 rows and 17 columns), where the little rectangles that make up the grid **would not change size** as I zoom in and out on the map.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 5):

There is a Leaflet plugin called [leaflet-virtual-grid](https://github.com/patrickarlt/leaflet-virtual-grid) (based on [L.Grid](https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet.Grid)) which does what you want. The provided examples need a few fixes to work, [here](https://pluton.cassio.pe/~julien/leaflet-virtual-grid/examples/events.html) is the result.

I didn't see any option to make the x and y length different.

Comment: Broken link to pluton!?

Comment: Can you please provide the example in another link?